# Update Activity text area from c2dm event listener

Tags: android

I want to update a layout element (TextArea) whenever a c2dm event is triggered, how can I get the view from the event listener?

Event listener, the 2 lines of interest are under the Message handling, update text area comment

```
public class C2DMMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    String action = intent.getAction();
                    Log.w("C2DM", "Message Receiver called");
                    if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(action)) {
                        Log.w("C2DM", "Received message");
                        final String payload = intent.getStringExtra("payload");
                        Log.d("C2DM", "dmControl: payload = " + payload);

                        // Message handling, update text area
                        if(payload.equals("DataUpdate")) {
                         t=(TextView) context.findViewById(R.id.gameConsoleText); 
    t.setText("evt rcvd!");
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
```

This line has the error, I can't get findViewByID from context

```
 t=(TextView) context.findViewById(R.id.gameConsoleText);
```

Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findViewById() only exists in Activities!

But you could use a [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) like this:

```
LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View myView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourView, null);
t = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.gameConsoleText);
```

But you should probably raise an intent to update your UI within your activitiy.